# "The application stays on (or in) the same screen."?

Tags: prepositions

> The application stays **on/in** the same screen.

***In*** sounds a lot better but aren't things ***on*** the screen?

Comment: An image which is projected would logically be "on the screen" - but one like a TV or computer screen image might equally logically be said to appear "in the screen". In practice, with cinema or projection I think I would always say "on the screen". But I'm not sure which I feel more comfortable with, as regards a TV or computer image.

Comment: What is it you’re trying to express?  The application is stuck on the same screen/page?  The application window can’t be moved to a different monitor? The application (e.g. a liquid being applied) is applied to the same screen as the previous step?  You are screening job applications and one application doesn’t move forward to the next screening step?  The choice of In or on may change based on the context.

Answer (score 1):

It's a matter of how a native English speaker chooses to perceive.

Many people believe that both the following sentences are grammatical.

**I'm on the bus to New Hampshire**

**I was in the bus not fifteen minutes ago**

Comment: Very good point. And the two examples carry different senses, each calling for the particular preposition you have provided.

Answer (score 0):

By convention, when there's a single screen, we invariably use the preposition ***on***. (There would be no question of "same" in this case, anyway.):

> The image stays ***on*** the screen for a fixed duration.
>   The names are displayed ***on*** the screen.

However, when there are multiple screens, as the question seems to imply, it is natural to use the preposition ***in***, instead. The implication then being that it is "a part of" (so, *in*) one or the other screen.

So is the case with "Window" or "Tab".

HTH.